# Time interval in SSRS expression

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Guys I have a question here. I have a matrix in SSRS 2008R2. I am looking for an expression that will group my date as Time (Hours and seconds). I want my date field to be in 8:01am - 9:00am, 9:01 - 10:00am and so on.

Here is ideal

```
 Time           |COUNT 1| COUNT 2 |
 8:01-9:00am    |  2    |     1   |
 9:01am-10:00am |  3    |     4   |
 10:01am-11:00am|  1    |     5   |
```

What is the best expression to use to get this working for the time part?

Comment: You are not clear what you want ? Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: The above table is a matrix. Row group is time while column group is the count. The time is actually a date column. All I am asking is the best ssrs expression to use to make the time in the format of intervals (8:01-9:00) and still group it. Make sense?

Comment: So you want to do the grouping on the basis of time interval of 1 hour  right ?

Comment: Yes. I need the ssrs expression for that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is built in method for that or not but, You can use a trick to achieve what you want using following steps

1) Add calculated field in your dataset

2) Set expression to that field to calculate the value base on time like if it between 09:01 - 10:00 then set it 09:00 if 10:01-11:00 then 10:00 and so on and so forth.

3) Then just apply the group by using that calculated field

That should achieve what you want.

1) Add calculated field in your dataset

[image]

2) Set expression to that field to calculate the value base on time like if it between 09:01 - 10:00 then set it 09:00 if 10:01-11:00 then 10:00 and so on and so forth.

```
   =Replace(CStr(FormatDateTime(Fields!YourDateTime.Value,4)),Right(CStr(FormatDateTime(Fields!YourDateTime.Value,4)),2),"01")
```

3) Then just apply the group by using that calculated field

[image]

after applying group by data looks like this.

If you want you can add the total also.
In case of issue comment.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the expression you are talking about?

Comment: I think it is getting closer.  Your calculated field is just assuming all the minutes are "01". I want the actual minutes in the date column. For example, your first row is 12/15/2013 5:24:34 pm. I want the calculated field to be 17:34. Does this make sense? Please tell me if I am missing something

Comment: So you can use your actual date column and apply the date time formatt from the properties

Comment: What i am saying is use the calculated field as grouping column and set it to visible false and then use it your actual date column with time format to show the value

Comment: I am showing the calculatedfield here so u can undersrand how it works you can set it to invisible

Comment: I think I have scaled that part now, the other issue is that ssrs does not like colon in expression. When I do =IIF(Fields!DateStart.Value>=09:01 AND Fields!DateStart.Value<=10:00,"9-10",Nothing), it throws an error

Comment: Why are you matching your values like that in expression and for which field ??

Comment: I do not think that you can use BETWEEN in ssrs expression. Do you have a sugestion?

Comment: its for the date column

Comment: Did You add the Calculated date column in dataset